# Firewall rules ambiguous?

Tags: firewall

In the stock OSX firewall settings I can add applications to the rules table, and then give them a red dot (block) or a green dot (allow).

I've got 6 apps in the table. Some green some red.

But what about the hundred other apps on my mac? Are they blocked or allowed?

Answer (score 1):

The firewall is designed to block incoming connections unless permission is granted (with the exception of certain essential system services and "sharing" services, such as File Sharing and Screen Sharing). The first time you use an application and it requests incoming network access, you will be prompted to allow or disallow. It is then added to the list and your decision is noted.

See [OS X: About the application firewall](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1810) on Apple's support website.

Comment: Ah, so apps are blocked by default, but the red dot still has a meaning:"don't ask the user about this app again, just keep it blocked."Thanks, you've saved me a lot of time here.

Comment: @user251764 You're welcome. If you feel I've answered your question, please accept it by clicking the green checkmark to the left.